# SQL to django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have the model:

```
class DeviceVals(Model):
    device_id = UUIDField()
    dt = DateTimeField()
    value = FloatField()
```

I need calculate sum of changes from this table, here is sql which works fine:

```
SELECT 
   dt,
   SUM(cons)
FROM
  (SELECT 
      device_id,
      dt,
      value,
      ("value" - LAG("value", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY "device_id"
                                       ORDER BY "dt" ASC)) AS "cons"
   FROM "devicevals") AS ss
GROUP BY "dt"
ORDER BY "dt";
```

I need to convert this sql to django ORM. How can I do that?

Comment: You want a sum of changes for every dt or a sum of changes for every device? I would expect dt to be fairly unique and your results to just be a dt and an individual change from your SQL

Comment: I need for every dt. There are always the identical pieces of time. Only days, months, and years differ.